# Show number on label, wait and show another. Xcode tools

Tags: xcode, label, delay, wait, xcode4.5

I need some help with xcode...
I need to show a value on label with [label1 setIntValue: someInt] wait some secs and do again [label1 setIntValue: otherInt]. I tried with sleep() but the ui stucks and only the second int is shown. What I need to do? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to set up a timer. After setting the first value on the label, use this:

```
NSTimer* t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target: self selector:@selector(timerEnded) userInfo: nil repeats:NO];
```

In this case you're waiting 1 second before triggering `timerEnded`. So, after this, create the `timerEnded` method. This is the method that gets called after 1 second.

```
-(void)timerEnded{
    //set value to label
}
```

Comment: if you find this answer helpful, click on the check on the left side of this answer. thank you!